# need to combine 2 formulas in 1 cell of excel

Tags: excel

My main goal:
1 excel file with Sheet1 & Sheet2, i want to write a formula in sheet 2, column E (cell-Row # 2), which should check IF Sheet 2 columns A, B & C (same row#2) matches exactly to sheet 1, Columns A, B & C (all rows in same sequence) then copy the record from Sheet 1, column D and add it to Sheet 2, Column E (same row which have an exact match).

the exact sample is below. please help, thank you.

Sheet 1 below:

| documentnumber | revisionno | sheetno | attachmentname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 107-10276 | 0 | 1 | testL070276.pdf |
| 102-15902 | 0 | 1 | tL020317.pdf |
| 115-10159 | 3 | 1 | vL150159.pdf |
| 103-10124 | 0 | 2 | hL030124.pdf |
| 111-10217 | 6 | 1 | nL110217.pdf |

sheet 2 below:

| Drawing No. | Revision | SheetNo |  | Attachment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 04/07/00 | 1 | 1 |  |  |
| 04/07/02 | 0 | 1 |  |  |
| 04/07/03 | 0 | 1 |  |  |
| 04/07/04 | 0 | 1 |  |  |
| 04/07/05 | 0 | 1 |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| 107-10276 | 0 | 1 |  |  |
| 102-15902 | 0 | 5 |  |  |
| 115-10159 | 3 | 1 |  |  |
| 103-10124 | 0 | 2 |  |  |
| 111-10217 | 6 | 1 |  |  |

thank you.

for testing purposes, i have tested a Simple formula for 1 column only, & other copy data formula, but am not able to combine.
=IF(Sheet1!A2:A4=Sheet2!A2:A4) & (=Sheet1!D2:D6)

appreciate if someone can advise on how to combine the above formula as well.

Comment: Do you mean if e.g. `Sheet2!A2:C2` is found in `Sheet1!A5:C5`, the formula in `Sheet2!F2` should return the value from `Sheet1!D5`?

Comment: NO, i am checking a way to upload the file for better understanding and further tests

Comment: Dont upload file instead use **[Markdown_Table_Generator](https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/)** to paste sample data as text. That would be easy for those looking to provide solutions.

Comment: as advised i have edited my question and pasted exact test sheets markdown, thank you

Comment: thank you for editing my post, will wait for your formula advise

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** to accommodate the edit in the question:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$6;MATCH(1;(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$6=A2)*(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$6=B2)*(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$6=C2);0));"NOT FOUND")`

Or slightly edited previous answer (forgot to absolute reference the ranges on sheet1):

`=XLOOKUP(A2&B2&C2;Sheet1!$A$2:$A$6&Sheet1!$B$2:$B$6&Sheet1!$C$2:$C$6;Sheet1!$D$2:$D$6;"NOT FOUND";0)`

I still don't understand your requirement of "same row on sheet2 = same row on sheet1" since your example would give 0 results in that regard.

---

The Xlookup function can do this for you, i.e.:

`=XLOOKUP(A2&B2&C2,Sheet1!A2:A4&Sheet1!B2:B4&Sheet1!C2:C4, Sheet1!F2:F4,"NOT FOUND")`

From your comment on the other answer, I suppose it's not just column 1,2 and 3 so that becomes:

`=XLOOKUP(A2&C2&D2,Sheet1!DW2:DW4&Sheet1!FL2:FL4&Sheet1!F2:F4, Sheet1!F2:F4,"NOT FOUND")`

Or this if you don't want to hardcode the range in Sheet1:
`=XLOOKUP(A2&C2&D2;FILTER(Sheet1!DW:DW;Sheet1!F:F<>"")&FILTER(Sheet1!FL:FL;Sheet1!F:F<>"")&FILTER(Sheet1!F:F;Sheet1!F:F<>""); FILTER(Sheet1!F:F;Sheet1!F:F<>"");"NOT FOUND")`

Comment: really appreciated all the help from the contributor members, is there a way i can upload that excel file with some details, so all can test your formulas, because, the above formula is giving value missing error. i will make the file with less data and less columns

Comment: i have edited my question and pasted exact test sheets markdown.

Comment: Edited my answer, let me know if it still doesn't work out.